# How to insert a blank row in Excel from c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a template that looks like this

```
My Header bla bla bla

name1  name2 name3


My footer bla bla bla
```

put a line in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataSource.Length; i++)
            {
                ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i+7, 1] = "row1";
                ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i+7, 2] = "row2";
                ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i+7, 3] = "row3";    
            }
```

and my table looks like:

```
My Header bla bla bla

    name1  name2 name3
    row1   row2   row3
    row1   row2   row3
    row1   row2   row3
```

data will be overwritten my footer.
so I want to insert a blank line loop that she put my footer at each step. but how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DataColumn dt= new DataColumn();
dt.Columns.Add("");

ObjWorkSheet.InsertDataColumn(dt, true, 1, 0);
```

In InsertDataColumn, first parameter is DataColumn,
second is columnheader, bool type (true or false),
third is row number, type int
fouth is column number, type int